# Why there are null values when I use group by?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have data on amazon's 50 best-selling books(from Kaggle). [image: first 5 rows]

There are no null values in the data.

Now, I find the mean of reviews given by the user[image: here]. Now, I use a group by function but it gives null values for User Ratings and mean. [image]

In the next step, I filter all those reviews where the reviews are greater than the average reviews.[image]

My question is: why did I get the null values in the first case? since there were no null values in the dataset?

Why did I get null values when I used group by?

[ipynb file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uBju4QsBg2-m6x_76rbk9c77Z2-uD0uI/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: Welcome. Try to show your codes in-line within your question.

Comment: Check if indeed data.Reviews is int as it appears in your data.head()

Comment: What does `data.Reviews.tolist()` shows.  You might want to check `data.loc[~data.Reviews.str.isdigit(), 'Reviews'].tolist()`

Comment: Perhaps, you could simply see what 1. `data.describe()` gives you to get a good representation of your dataset, and 2. check indeed there are no NaN/null ||  `data.isnull().values.any()`  | `data.isnull().any().any()` |  `data.isnull().sum` |  `data.isnull().sum().sum()` | `data.Reviews.isnull().any()`

Comment: I tried reproducing your 'error' with the Amazon Top 50 Bestselling Books 2009 - 2019 dataset. I was unable to. ***For easy comprehension, I'll post as an 'Answer'***

Comment: Probably it's just from my side. The #edit by @Siva Shanmugam seems to remove TANNU's img URL. Can the original links be left behind alongside putting them in-line. Also, can the codes be in text and not images.

Comment: Have added ipynb file for your reference

Comment: Please [do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add the information as text (within code fences etc.) instead. Linking to an external ipynb-file doesn't make the question self-contained. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and take look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This 'Answer' is an attempt at #**reproducibility**.
The OP *question cannot be reproduced*.
PS: The `groupby` returns grouping as 'expected'.

@TANNU, It appears your '`NaN`' might have come from your data cleansing. Kindly show your relevant code.
NB: The ['Amazon Top 50 Bestselling Books 2009 - 2019' dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sootersaalu/amazon-top-50-bestselling-books-2009-2019) has #550 rows {`data.shape`:`(550, 7)`}
[For noting]
Your `book_review` groupby has a whopping `269010 rows`. My reproduction of your `book_review` yielded `351 rows × 5 columns`
PS: Updated based on @Siva Shanmugam's edit.

```py
## import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

## read dataset
data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dphi-official/Datasets/master/Amazon%20Top%2050%20Bestselling%20Books%202009%20-%202019.csv')
data.head(2)

''' [out]
Name    Author  User Rating Reviews Price   Year    Genre
0   10-Day Green Smoothie Cleanse   JJ Smith    4.7 17350   8   2016    Non Fiction
1   11/22/63: A Novel   Stephen King    4.6 2052    22  2011    Fiction
'''

## check shape
data.shape
''' [out]
(550, 7)
'''

## check dataset
data.describe()
''' [out]

User Rating Reviews Price   Year
count   550.000000  550.000000  550.000000  550.000000
mean    4.618364    11953.281818    13.100000   2014.000000
std 0.226980    11731.132017    10.842262   3.165156
min 3.300000    37.000000   0.000000    2009.000000
25% 4.500000    4058.000000 7.000000    2011.000000
50% 4.700000    8580.000000 11.000000   2014.000000
75% 4.800000    17253.250000    16.000000   2017.000000
max 4.900000    87841.000000    105.000000  2019.000000
'''

## check NaN
data.Reviews.isnull().any().any()
''' [out]
False
'''

## mean of reviews
mean_reviews = np.math.ceil(data.Reviews.mean())
mean_reviews
''' [out]
11954
'''

## group by mean of `User Rating` and `Reviews`
book_review = data.groupby(['Name', 'Author', 'Genre'], as_index=False)[['User Rating', 'Reviews']].mean()
book_review
''' [out] 
Name    Author  Genre   User Rating Reviews
0   10-Day Green Smoothie Cleanse   JJ Smith    Non Fiction 4.7 17350.0
2   12 Rules for Life: An Antidote to Chaos Jordan B. Peterson  Non Fiction 4.7 18979.0
3   1984 (Signet Classics)  George Orwell   Fiction 4.7 21424.0
5   A Dance with Dragons (A Song of Ice and Fire)   George R. R. Martin Fiction 4.4 12643.0
6   A Game of Thrones / A Clash of Kings / A Storm...   George R. R. Martin Fiction 4.7 19735.0
... ... ... ... ... ...
341 When Breath Becomes Air Paul Kalanithi  Non Fiction 4.8 13779.0
342 Where the Crawdads Sing Delia Owens Fiction 4.8 87841.0
345 Wild: From Lost to Found on the Pacific Crest ...   Cheryl Strayed  Non Fiction 4.4 17044.0
348 Wonder  R. J. Palacio   Fiction 4.8 21625.0
350 You Are a Badass: How to Stop Doubting Your Gr...   Jen Sincero Non Fiction 4.7 14331.0
83 rows × 5 columns
'''


## get book reviews that are less than the mean(reviews)
book_review[book_review.Reviews < mean_reviews]
''' [out]
    Name    Author  Genre   User Rating Reviews
​
'''
```

[image: reproduction of book_review groupby]